# Clojure changing namespace in uberjar

Tags: clojure, namespaces, leiningen

I'm having trouble changing the namespace in Clojure. When I'm in the REPL, or even when I do lein run, I can use

```
(ns ppm.core)
(in-ns ppm.core)
```

However, when I convert it into an uberjar, I get "Can't change/establish root binding of: *ns* with set" as an error. This is really frustrating me cause I'm using jars to hand in my homework, and I can't find anything to fix it. Is there a way to either set the namespace to my file, or simply import the functions into the user namespace?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve here, could you elaborate? I guess you could be looking for the `:require` statement of the `ns` macro?

Comment: When I run my code in the REPL, the namespace defaults to that of the core file, namely ppm.core. When I compile it with "lein run" or "lein uberjar", it defaults to the user namespace. I would like to either switch to the ppm.core namespace or import the functions from ppm.core into the user namespace

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're aiming for, so I'm taking more guesses. First, you can specify a `:main` function in your `project.clj` that will run when `lein run` or `uberjar` are executed. This function could simply be in your `ppm.core` namespace, not need to import it. If you start a repl, you can also specify a namespace that the repl will start in via the `:init-ns` option (inside the `:repl` options).

Comment: `(in-ns ppm.core)` should be `(in-ns 'ppm.core)`